# Stack frame NULL in backtrace log

Tags: c, gdb, libcurl, debug-backtrace

My application is receiving the segmentation fault. The back trace log -

```
Program received signal SIGSEV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004a5c03 in engine_unlocked_finish ()

(gdb) bt

#0  0x00000000004a5c03 in engine_unlocked_finish ()
#1  0x00000000004a5d71 in ENGINE_finish ()
#2  0x000000000046a537 in EVP_PKEY_free_it ()
#3  0x000000000046a91b in EVP_PKEY_free ()
#4  0x00000000004b231a in pubkey_cb ()
#5  0x0000000000470c97 in asn1_item_combine_free ()
#6  0x0000000000750f70 in X509_CINF_seq_tt ()
#7  0x00000000010f7d90 in ?? ()
#8  0x00000000010f7cf0 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

The stackframe at `#9` is interesting. It's address is `0x0000000000000000`. Does this mean stack got corrupted even before getting to `engine_unlocked_finish ()` ?

Comment: Yes, you have corrupted your stack frame. Compile at least with `gcc -Wall -g`, perhaps also with `-fsanitize=address`; use also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: `-fstack-protector-all` might also help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The stackframe at #9 is interesting.

Not really. What's most likely happening is that `X509_CINF_seq_tt` is hand-coded assembly, and lacks correct unwind descriptors, so everything after it in the stack trace is just bogus.

In fact, looking at this [source](http://www.opencoverage.net/libressl/index_html/source_84_preprocessed.html), `X509_CINF_seq_tt` is not even a function, so it's probably `asn1_item_combine_free` that starts the "bad unwind".